# Stacked Bar Chart with Time Series Data

Tags: csv, d3.js

I am new to D3.js and am using **D3 v4** for this. I have already seen https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208.

Here is the .csv file (**test_data.csv**):

```
date,col_1,col_2
11/1/2012,1977652,1802851
12/1/2012,1128739,948687
1/1/2013,1201944,1514667
2/1/2013,1863148,1834006
3/1/2013,1314851,1906060
4/1/2013,1283943,1978702
5/1/2013,1127964,1195606
6/1/2013,1773254,977214
7/1/2013,1929574,1127450
8/1/2013,1980411,1808161
9/1/2013,1405691,1182788
10/1/2013,1336790,937890
11/1/2013,1851053,1358400
12/1/2013,1472623,1214610
1/1/2014,1155116,1757052
2/1/2014,1571611,1935038
3/1/2014,1898348,1320348
4/1/2014,1444838,1934789
5/1/2014,1235087,950194
6/1/2014,1272040,1580656
7/1/2014,980781,1680164
8/1/2014,1391291,1115999
9/1/2014,1211125,1542148
10/1/2014,1020824,1782795
11/1/2014,1685081,926612
12/1/2014,1469254,1767071
1/1/2015,1168523,935897
2/1/2015,1602610,1450541
3/1/2015,1830278,1354876
4/1/2015,1275158,1412555
5/1/2015,1560961,1839718
6/1/2015,949948,1587130
7/1/2015,1413765,1494446
8/1/2015,1166141,1305105
9/1/2015,958975,1202219
10/1/2015,902696,1023987
11/1/2015,961441,1865628
12/1/2015,1363145,1954046
1/1/2016,1862878,1470741
2/1/2016,1723891,1042760
3/1/2016,1906747,1169012
4/1/2016,1963364,1927063
5/1/2016,1899735,1936915
6/1/2016,1300369,1430697
7/1/2016,1777108,1401210
8/1/2016,1597045,1566763
9/1/2016,1558287,1140057
10/1/2016,1965665,1953595
11/1/2016,1800438,937551
12/1/2016,1689152,1221895
1/1/2017,1607824,1963282
2/1/2017,1878431,1415658
3/1/2017,1730296,1947106
4/1/2017,1956756,1696780
5/1/2017,1746673,1662892
6/1/2017,989702,1537646
7/1/2017,1098812,1592064
8/1/2017,1861973,1892987
9/1/2017,1129596,1406514
10/1/2017,1528632,1725020
11/1/2017,925850,1795575
```

Here is **page.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208 -->
<style>

rect.bar { fill: steelblue; }

</style>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<body>

<script>
var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
            
var g = svg.append("g")
           .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
            
// parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");

var x = d3.scaleTime()
          .domain([new Date(2012, 11, 1), new Date(2017, 11, 31)])
          .range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var z = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(["#F1F1F1", "#CE1126"])

// load .csv file
d3.csv("test_data.csv", function(d, i, columns) {
  for (i = 1, t = 0; i < columns.length; ++i) t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
  d.total = t;
  return d;
}, function(error, data){
    if (error) throw error;
    
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    });
    
    var keys = data.columns.slice(1);
    
    data.sort(function(a, b) { return b.date - a.date; });
    x.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.date }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.total; })]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);
    
    console.log(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data));
    
    g.append("g")
     .selectAll("g")
     .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
     .enter().append("g")
     .attr("fill", function(d) { return z(d.key); })
     .selectAll("rect")
     .data(function(d) { return d; })
     .enter()
     .append("rect")
     .attr("x", function(d) { return console.log(x(d.data.date)); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d[0]) - y(d[1]); })
     .attr("width", x.bandwidth());
    
    
});
</script>

</body>
```

My aim is to create a stacked bar chart **by month based on the link above** (so each tick corresponds to a month), of the values in `col_1` and `col_2`.

Some errors I've received:

1. `console.log(x(d.data.date))`, for some reason, does not return the actual date.
2. The following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: x.bandwidth is not a function
>
> at page.html:65
>
> at Object. (d3.v4.js:11453)
>
> at Dispatch.call (d3.v4.js:792)
>
> at XMLHttpRequest.respond (d3.v4.js:11378)

I think this error might have something to do with the fact that I'm using `scaleTime`, rather than `scaleBand`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try using the width/data.length to calculate bar widths evenly.  Perhaps add some pixels as buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues with your dates, which need to be in working order to use a time scale.

Firstly, Your date format is `4/1/2015` but you are parsing it with `d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");`

You will only get null values parsing with this, to see this try:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    console.log(d.date); // null
});
```

As you use slashes rather than dashes, and you use month, day, year, try:

```
d3.timeParse("%m/%d/%Y");
```

---

Secondly, and related to dates is that you set an initial domain based on hard coded minimum and maximum dates, that works, but you overwrite it with this:

```
 x.domain(data.map(function(d){ return d.date }));
```

A timescale domain takes in a minimum and a maximum for the domain. You are providing an array of every value, instead, use:

```
x.domain(d3.extent( data, function(d){ return d.date }) );
```

---

On to the graph and bar width, `.bandwidth()` isn't a method of a continuous scale (hence your error: "Uncaught TypeError: x.bandwidth is not a function"). In a continuous scale the bars are placed based on their value,  there is no natural bar width (bars are not placed with regular spacing unless the increment between each data value is the same).

As you have a data point for each month (there are no holes in the data), and each data point represents an equal length in time, we can set bar width to be a fraction of the plot area width, where the width of the plot area is split equally between each data point:

```
(width-margin.right-margin.left)/data.length
```

Here's your graph with these changes:

[image]

And here's a working [example](https://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/45239d3d80a115d2ee4360c57239e9ed).

---

Lastly, note that you need to return a value here:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { return console.log(x(d.data.date)); })
```

Log before the return statement if you want to debug:

```
.attr("x", function(d) { console.log(x(d.date.date)); return x(d.data.date); })
```